# How to determine whether it is an entire series modification from the GetItem response?

Tags: exchange-server

The below issues we are facing when working with recurrence modification using Exchange 2010 EWS.

(1) When a recurrence series is modified how to determine whether it is an entire series modification from the GetItem response?

(2) When single occurrence is modified the modified occurrence information is available in the ModifiedOccurrences collection.  How to determine the last modified occurrence from the ModifiedOccurrences collection?

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this Chirag? I'm trying to work out the same thing myself now....